# Responsive or Transparent background image

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating a container with a background image behind. I have no problem in desktop or bigger sizes. However when the window resizes the text comes on the top of the image and the text becomes unreadable. Do you have a solution about this? Maybe change the opacity of the image in smaller sizes or completely remove the background image and use an img src instead? Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/10875/)

```
<div class=" network container-fluid">
<div class="row">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-md-6"></div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
             <h1> Lorem Ipsume</h1>

            <br>
            <br>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting</p>
        </div>
        <br>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
.network {
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/w5BnMSf.png), #f6f8f8;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 50%;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: contain;
    width: 100%;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
}
.network h1 {
    font-family:'Open Sans', arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 49.4000015258789px;
    color: dimgray;
    padding-top: 40px;
}
.network p {
    font-family:'Open Sans', arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 19.4000015258789px;
    color: dimgray;
    text-align: justify;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified your HTML and CSS a bit and i think this is the result that you want:

HTML:

```
  <div class=" network container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="col-xs-6 img pull-left"></div>
                <div class="col-xs-6 pull-left">
                  <h1> Lorem Ipsume</h1>
                <br>
                <br>

               <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting</p>  
                </div>

                    <br style="clear:both;" />
        </div>


        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.img {
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/w5BnMSf.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 500px;
    background-size: contain;
    background-position:50% 50%;
}
.network {
    background-color:#f6f8f8;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
}
.network h1 {
         font-family: 'Open Sans', arial, sans-serif;
         font-weight: 300;
         font-size: 49.4000015258789px;
         color: dimgray;
         padding-top: 40px;
}
.network p {
        font-family: 'Open Sans', arial, sans-serif;
        font-weight: 300;
        font-size: 19.4000015258789px;
         color: dimgray;
        text-align: justify;
}
```

Here's a solution in [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/10879/)

Hope this helps :-)

Comment: thanks that worked! but can i make the image larger?

Comment: welcome, yes but not recommended because of the responsiveness :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a media query to change the opacity or remove the background when a certain height is reached. You can as media queries dependent on height / width / both, etc...

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/10882/) - play with height of iframe by pulling the separator between the css box, and preview box up and down.

```
.network {
    position: relative;
    height: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.24);
}

.network::before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/w5BnMSf.png) , #f6f8f8;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: contain;
    content: '';
}

@media (max-height: 700px) { /** play with the numbers to find the right height **/
  .network::before {
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
}

@media (max-height: 500px) { /** play with the numbers to find the right height **/
  .network::before {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also make text-shadow trick on a small screens.

https://jsfiddle.net/azvmaby1/

```
@media (max-width: 768px){
p {
    text-shadow: #f6f8f8 1px 0px, #f6f8f8 1px 1px, #f6f8f8 0px 1px, #f6f8f8 -1px 1px, #f6f8f8 -1px 0px, #f6f8f8 -1px -1px, #f6f8f8 0px -1px, #f6f8f8 1px -1px, #f6f8f8 0 0 3px, #f6f8f8 0 0 3px, #f6f8f8 0 0 3px, #f6f8f8 0 0 3px, #f6f8f8 0 0 3px, #f6f8f8 0 0 3px, #f6f8f8 0 0 3px, #f6f8f8 0 0 3px;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use a transparent or a translucent div to hold my text so it makes an impression

1. Here is how :: **Transparent**

--PS: the opacity is your call when it feels right

```
.container{background:rgba(255,255,255,0.6);}
```

1. Also you can use **Translucent blur**

```
.container{
  -webkit-filter: blur(10px);
  filter: url('blur.svg');/*look below for creating blur.svg*/
  filter: blur(10px);
}
```

create blur.svg // copy contents into a file and save it as blur.svg

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <filter id="blur">
    <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="10" />
  </filter>
</svg>
```

Comment: that makes the picture transparent?

Comment: yes if you add this to the div pic tag it will use a gaussian blur so that the text is crispy, but make the div holding the pic absolute, one bad thing is that it will blur everything all children blur.

Reference : http://jordanhollinger.com/2014/01/29/css-gaussian-blur-behind-a-translucent-box/